# Linkedin post card: successfully fetched og:image on localhost (through ngrok) but fetched wrong image (inside site content) on remote dev server

Tags: nuxt.js, linkedin-api, ngrok, share-open-graph

I am trying to display the correct image on linkedin post card. The source code on dev server and my local machine (which I use ngrok to proxy to) is the same, the page source also render the same meta tags.

But when I use inspect (https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector) to compare 2 environment. The local machine show the image in og:image, but the dev server return the first image in the content (`<img />` tag).

Sorry, I can not post the images here because it's not public for now.

Does the linkedin inspector really clear the cache when I hit inspect button? (The image meta tag was added before this and we ran inspect this site once).

I am using nuxt 2 for frontend and wordpress for backend (headless mode).